# Can my pendingIntent in AlarmManager be deleted or canceled by the system?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-developer-api

can the system in android delete or cancel my PendingIntent I send to AlarmManager intentionally i.e. for free up resources?

Comment: No. Android won't cancel or delete scheduled alarms to free up resources. Be aware that alarms are not persistent across device reboots.

Comment: @david, thank you. That confirm my though now. I aware about the reboots already. But not about this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Android won't cancel or delete scheduled alarms to free up resources. Be aware that alarms are not persistent across device reboots.

NOTE: I answered this so we can get it off the "open questions" list.